# How to access the first word in a button text

Tags: html, css, button, underline

here is my code

```
<button class="mcnTextContent"  type="button" style="text-decoration:underline">Click here to Reactivate your account before Feb. 1, 2016 for FREE</button>
```

I want to make first word (Click) only underlined . Can anyone please help me to figure that out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the word Click in a styled `span` like so

```
<button class="mcnTextContent"  type="button"><span style="text-decoration:underline">Click</span> here to Reactivate your account before Feb. 1, 2016 for FREE</button>
```

[Original Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmf0m8px/)

I also recommend **not** using in-line styling, so here it is without in-line css

**CSS**

```
#underline{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="mcnTextContent"  type="button">
    <span id="underline">Click</span> here to Reactivate your account beforeFeb. 1, 2016 for FREE
</button>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7mkrt7p/)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why in-line styling is bad.  I was about to recommend it.  (In-line meaning surround "Click" with a <u></u> right?)

Comment: In-line styling refers to the `style` attribute of a tag. i.e `<a style=""/>`, it's not recommended to do this because it increases your `HTML` code length and is hard to maintain

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class="mcnTextContent"  type="button" >
    <span style="text-decoration:underline;">Click</span> here to Reactivate your account before Feb. 1, 2016 for FREE
</button>
```